# How do I shorten this grep command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I want my grep command to be shorter, e.g., to be able to just type `g` on the command line to execute `grep` with options  `-Pei`.

I've tried with an alias in Bash, but piping doesn't work.

```
 alias g='grep --color auto -Pei'
```

gives me

```
 history |g qemu
 grep: auto: No such file or directory
 grep: qemu: No such file or directory
```

I then tried in `.bashrc`

```
 function g () { /bin/grep -Pei "$@" ;}
```

it still outputs

```
 history |g qemu
 grep: qemu: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Which version of grep do you use, GNU or BSD ?

Comment: Aliases work by replacing the first word of the command with something else, and executing the result. This means that if the full command `grep --color auto -Pei qemu` doesn't work, then creating the `alias g='grep --color auto -Pei'` and running `g qemu` cannot work either, because they expand to the exact same command. Try writing out a full, working command first, before aliasing it.

Comment: Thorsten, your problem has been solved, which is great for _you_. Marking an answer as accepted (whether it's mine or not) helps _others_ (future readers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate problems with your alias:

- long-form GNU options (those starting with `--` rather than `-`) require a `=` between the option name and its value (argument):

  - I.e., it should be `--color=auto`, not `--color auto`
- you're using option `-e` incorrectly: its purpose is to accept *multiple* search patterns, with *each* `-e` instance *requiring an argument* - in your case, `[-]e` is directly followed by `i`, which therefore mistakenly serves as `-e`'s argument, i.e., as the *pattern*, causing your true search pattern to be misinterpreted as a *filename* operand.

Thus, redefine your alias as follows:

```
alias g='grep --color=auto -Pi'
```

*Update*: As [tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29323999/45375) implies, using `-e` has one advantage: it allows you to specify patterns that *start with a `-`* without getting misinterpreted as further options; thus, placing `-e` *last* in the alias will give you that advantage.

```
alias g='grep --color=auto -Pie'
```

Of course, not building `-e` into the alias always leaves you the option to specify it *on demand*, when *invoking* the alias, which would make the use of *multiple* `-e` options more intuitable.

---

Finally, the advice given by @thatotherguy in a comment is worth heeding:

Before defining an alias, make sure that its definition works as expected as a directly entered command.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Thorsten. For the benefit of both respondents and future readers: If an answer _solves_ your problem, please _accept it_ by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you find an answer _helpful_, please _up-vote_ it by clicking the up-arrow icon. (You may do both.)

Answer (score 1):

The option `-e` is incorrect. The way you are using it, you are specifying that the search expression is `i` (that is, `-Pei` is interpreted as `-P -e i`, not `-P -e -i`). Switch to `-Pie` (or just `-Pi` if you don't anticipate needing to search for expressions which start with a dash).

In the first attempt, you also need an equals sign instead of a space between `color` and `auto`.

You should generally prefer functions over aliases, although in this limited scenario, an alias works, too.

The `function` keyword is a bashism; removing it improves the portability of your code.

Don't specify the path to `grep`; instead, make sure your `PATH` is sane.

```
g () { grep -Pie "$@" ;}
```

Comment: + for pointing out that `-e` can be helpful with patterns starting with a `-`